# How to I properly re-throw http req.on('error', (error) => {} error?

Tags: node.js

I'm setting up a little Kubernetes Job to upload a repair catalog to my server in an AKS cluster using an endpoint, basically it will just execute the `uploadRepairCatalog()` javascript function at startup.

Inside the `try` block of `uploadRepairCatalog()` function I first call
`createFirebaseUser()` which creates the `authToken` needed by the server endpoint.
Then I call `sendRepairData()` which inside a loop makes the http calls to the endpoint  and they both throw.
If any error is thrown by the previous two functions, inside `uploadRepairCatalog()`'s `catch (error)` block I call `deleteRepairs()` which delete whatever `sendRepairData()` eventually managed to save in the db before throwing an error, and I re-throw the error so the container fails and it all restarts.
At last insight the `finally` block I call `deleteFirebaseUser()` to cleanup Firebase from the initially created user.
As I'm running the code locally `sendRepairData()` always throws as it doesn't connect to the server.
I'm expecting the `deleteFirebaseUser()` to be called every time `uploadRepairCatalog()` enters the `finally` block but whenever an error is thrown by `sendRepairData()` it isn't called, so user isn't deleted.
If I start the code again then `createFirebaseUser()` throws as the user already exists, but then it `finally` does run `deleteFirebaseUser()`.

Trying to debugging it I saw that the problem is that I'm trying to re-throw the error from `sendRepairData()`'s `req.on('error', (error) => {}` but then it's not caught by `sendRepairData()` `catch` block, hence is not re-thrown to be caught by `uploadRepairCatalog()` `catch` block. I confirmed it by trowing a general Error instead of re-throwing `req.on('error', (error) => {}` error and with that it all works as expected.

How to I properly re-throw `req.on('error', (error) => {}` error?

```
async function sendRepairData() {
  // Read the catalog JSON file
  try {
    const catalogData = fs.readFileSync('catalog.json'); 
    const catalog = JSON.parse(catalogData);

    // Access the repairs array from the catalog
    repairs = catalog.repairs;
    console.log('expected repairs to send: ', repairs.length);

    for (const repair of repairs) {
      const options = {
        host: host,
        port: port,
        path: path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          AuthToken: authToken,
          apikey: apiKey,
        },
      };

      const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
        let data = '';

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
          console.log('Response:', data);
          // save response data for resetting the db in case of error
          savedRepairs.push(JSON.parse(data));
        });
      });

      req.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log('sendRepairData() http request error:', error);
        throw error; // this should get caught by the catch block to be re-thrown but it doesn't.
        // throw Error(`${error.name}, ${error.message}, ${error.stack}`);
      });

      req.write(JSON.stringify(repair));
      req.end();
      // throw Error('test error from sendRepairData()'); // throwing this error works
    } 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('\n\nsendRepairData() catch\n\nerror :', error);
    throw error;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split your code in multiple functions:

```js
async function getData() {
    const data = await fs.readFileSync("catalog.json");
    const catalog = JSON.parse(data);
    return catalog.repairs;
}

async function sendRepair(repair, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
            let data = "";
            res.on("data", (chunk) => (data += chunk));
            res.on("end", () => resolve(JSON.parse(data)));
        });
        req.on("error", reject);
        req.end(JSON.stringify(repair));
    });
}

async function sendRepairs(repairs) {
    const options = {
        host,
        port,
        path,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            AuthToken: authToken,
            apikey: apiKey,
        },
    };
    await Promise.all(repairs.map((repair) => sendRepair(repair, options)));
}
```

Since the HTTP request is now wrapped in a Promise, you can orchestrate everything as:

```js
const repairs = await getData();
try {
  await sendRepairs();
} catch(error) {
  // handle the error somehow
}
```

I would also try [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) instead of the native HTTP package, to make your life easier.

Comment: Hi, indeed I was looking into node-fetch. did you mean  `await Promise.all(repairs.map((repair) => sendRepair(repair, options)));` ?

Comment: when I run your code I get the error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "cb" argument must be of type function. Received undefined` from sendRepair I guess.

Comment: the error did actually come from `getData()` which uses `readFile` instead of `readFileSync`. I edited your answer and it's now working as expected.

Comment: You can still use `readFile` if you import it from `fs/promises` -> [see example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nckccp) ^^ bella Vince' buona giornata!

Comment: ah ok.. grazie mille e buona giornata anche a te!
Yes..we're Italians